# Audio file to waveform using PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for PHP class which will take an audio file and them return an image file of the waveform - similar effect can be seen here http://soundcloud.com/rollin-fire-cru/sets/house-house-house-house/

It should run on a linux server and accept the following audio file formats: mp3, mp4, aac, wav

I found an example class, but it does a very basic job
http://phpclasses.ca/package/482-PHP-Extracts-attributes-of-audio-files-Visualization.html

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: A bit of clarification: there's a bunch of other things in the example above (http://soundcloud.com/rollin-fire-cru/sets/house-house-house-house/) - I need only the image of the wave

Answer (score 2):

All sane sites does this as a background job, preferably in a faster language (e.g.: C++).

You have to decode all the formats to raw audio (wav), then create an image from that. Preferably on the fly meaning as soon as you decode a chunk of audio you draw the image for that chunk. Most codecs compress the data to 5-20% of the original size, so if you have a 10M file you suddenly have 50-200M of raw data... and if you have a 100M DJ mix.. well.. you get the point.

After the background process finished, you can simply serve the generated image with your favorite web-server.

Although it's possible to do all of this in PHP I wouldn't recommend it.