# mp3 to wav on linux via PHP

Tags: php, linux, lame

I want your advice on how to convert mp3 files to wav on linux via a PHP script.

I was successful with lame but only on windows, I putted `lame.exe` and `lame.xxx.dll` together and executed the PHP script posted here:

- [Generating MP3 waveforms with PHP (by Andrew; 29 April 2010)](http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/)

But so far so good, I'm not successful in doing the same thing on Linux.

Comment: Which linux? There are many distributions, and they make it normally very easy to install lame.

Comment: Related: [Audio file to waveform using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466439/audio-file-to-waveform-using-php); [Is there a PHP library to generate an waveform images out of an audio file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2522652/367456); [How does soundcloud.com generate the waveform for their MP3 player?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381243/367456); [Rendering waveform in PHP - How to produce a more compressed render?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8714215/367456)

Comment: @hakre I don't really know this, but I'm on a shared server from hostgator

Comment: Contact your hoster's support line and ask if they offer lame on their servers. And if they don't offer it, ask if you can install it your own and how to do that on their hosting plan.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lame`? `sudo yum install lame`? `sudo insert_package_manager_here install lame`?

Comment: I can't use those vars, that's the real problem, sorry

Answer (score 3):

sorry, but afaik php is only gonna let you mess with id3 tags. you're gonna want to use an external tool to get this done.

use lame:

```
exec("lame –decode input.mp3 output.wav");
```

or use mpg123:

```
exec("mpg123 -w output.wav input.mp3");
```

Comment: Take a closer look on the question, it asks how to install lame, not how to invoke it.

Comment: But doesn't mention the linux distribution.

Comment: That's why I asked it in the comment below the question. I can't tell you either.

Comment: The hard thing is that on shared server you(atleast me) can't use CL, so I'm trying to accomplish this task via PHP

Comment: also lame don't work without that `lame.exe` or `lame.dll` file and atleast I know that *.exe files can't be executed on linux, so it would be great if you tell me how to use `lame` on a shared hosting server

Comment: see http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/latest/download or http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123/files/latest/download. once you've got one or the other downloaded, open a terminal. if you downloaded a .tar.bz file, do "tar -jxvvf filename", or if you downloaded a .tar.gz file, do "tar -zxvvf filename". should create a new folder with a bunch of stuff in it. do "cd foldername". then do "./configure && make". if you have no errors, you may need to do "su" to login as root, then do "make install".

Comment: if you're on a shared server you probably will not be able to install either lame or mpg123.

Comment: thanks but I can't open the terminal on my host since I'm on a shared host not dedicated, it would be a great help if you could tell me that how to get the highest `amplitude` from a 1sec mp3 file

Answer (score 1):

I am using mpg123 to convert *.mp3 files into *.wav.

// To install mpg123 {Ubuntu 12.04}
sudo apt-get install mpg321

// My PHP Script (Sample)

```
<?php

# glob() :  to collect all files in a folder
# foreach() : to loop

foreach (glob("*.mp3") as $file)
{
    $act_name = explode ('.', $file);

    $command = "mpg123 -w {$act_name[0]}.wav $file";
    echo $command . "\n";
    exec($command)  
    echo "file converted {$file}\n";

    sleep(1);
}
```